# What does CBI mean in block 36 of discharge form WD AGO Form 53-55?

Tags: world-war-two, identification

I have recently received a copy of my uncle's WWII discharge form (WD AGO Form 53-55) and cannot find a source that defines the destination acronym of "CBI" listed in Block 36.

Does anyone have the definition and/or location of a publication that lists the form's acceptable entries?

[image: WD AGO Form 53-55]

Answer (score 15):

Note the box is indicating a location/destination, so the [CBI designation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Burma_India_Theater) would indicate [the China-Burma-India Theater](https://www.archives.gov/research/guide-fed-records/groups/493.html#:%7E:text=was%20referred%20to%20as%20the%20China%2DBurma%2DIndia%20(CBI)%20Theater.).